# How to make an api call anonymously with Sylius-standard?

Tags: rest, api, symfony, sylius

I'm looking for a way with Sylius to dynamically display the product list. Like asking the server for a specific set of products (search with parameters I suppose) asynchronously.

[The doc seems to suggest](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/api.html) the use of oauth authentication is mandatory but it's not what I'd like, or at least not systematically. So my question is, can I and how can I make an api call for "public" parts like product list but anonymously?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/api/authorization.html) :

> Sylius has the OAuth2 authorization configured. The authorization process is a standard procedure. Authorize as **admin** and enjoy the API!
>
> User has to have the **ROLE_API_ACCESS** role in order to access **/api** resources

So unless you create your own public api set to display products informations this is not possible with base Sylius api.

Comment: Did you work with it ? I mean with the api. Did you found some configuration file related to that ? I didn't find anything in the doc about extending/overriding the current api behavior, did you ? I suppose I can add a proxy-like logic but it seems ugly, hard to maintain and not very perfomance oriented (which is important for SEO).

Comment: Look for [SyliusApiBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/api-bundle) inside the vendors, you will find api specs and maybe you can use it as example to create your own public api. I have not work with it yet, I am testing it on a docker stack actually. Working good.

Comment: Look up the SampleToken in the API related tables and copy and name it. This is an example of a not expiring API Token which can access public routes...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SyliusShopApiPlugin](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusShopApiPlugin), which is currently in development. With it you can make anonymous and public API calls, e.g.:

```
/shop-api/taxons/t-shirts/products/?channel=US_WEB
```

to get all products in the t-shirts category.

I didn't find yet any documentation, but you can check the tests, e.g. https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusShopApiPlugin/blob/master/tests/Controller/ShowProductCatalogApiTest.php to get more examples.

Comment: Thank you for interesting answer. That being said, this api seems very lite. I just don't get why they didn't make something like a "search builder" in which you can specify what is it you let your user to search for (don't tell me about their horrible grid logic please...), or provide a simple interface to build query or something else... Also, using elastic search and being forced to repopulate the db after each update in the sylius isn't viable IMO. I don't want to start a discussion and it's not even related to the initial subject. Just letting my frustration express itself. ^^